# What does it mean "to smear an operator" in QFT?

Tags: field-theory, terminology

If possible, try to keep it physical (not too mathy). If I'm right, this smearing is necessary to determine the position of a particle in QFT. Why is that necessary? And please, spare my poor soul from a lot a math ;-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: It basically means to average it in a way whose consequences are well-understood by dint of linearity in the problem. If you smear jam on toast to uniform thickness, you can thereby determine its total volume.

Comment: You are likely referring to smearing operators, not functions? You smear an operator with a function, for instance $O[f] = \int dx f(x) O(x)$.

Comment: Yes, operators. Thanks! But what does it mean in words. Can you paint me a picture?

Comment: @VeronicaNoordzee I don't understand what else you want. I can't say any words that'll explain what smearing means more than that equation.

Answer (score 5):

Fundamental particles in QFT are mathematical points with no size. This leads to so-called "ultraviolet" (or short-distance) divergences (infinities) as the distance between two particles becomes arbitrarily small. The "smoothing" procedure is one way to "regulate" (or make finite) the divergences by averaging the position of the particle over some small but finite volume. This effectively treats the particle as if it had some size, which mathematically tames the divergences. Of course we are ultimately interested in taking the limit where the size of the particle goes to zero, so smoothing is usually just the first step in a process to understand how to take this limit consistently.

You may be familiar with the potential of a point charge in electromagnetism
\begin{equation}
V(r) = k \frac{q}{r}
\end{equation}
where $k$ is Coulomb's constant, $q$ is the charge of the particle, and $r$ is the distance from the particle. As $r\rightarrow 0$, $V\rightarrow \infty$. This is an example of an ultraviolet divergence as you get arbitrarily close to a point particle. One manifestation of this divergence is that the *self-energy* of the point charge $U = \frac{1}{8\pi k}\int d^3 x E^2$ (where $E$ is the electric field) is infinite.

An example of a "smoothing" procedure would be to replace the charged particle with a ball of radius $a$ with the same charge. Then the maximum value of the potential is $V(a) = k q / a$; inside the ball, the potential drops smoothly to zero, rather than racing off to infinity. The self energy is finite.

Comment: Andrew, thank you so much for keeping it simple. It gives me some intuition. Smearing, smoothing, regulating and making finite. Yes, there is a picture developing in my head ;-) I hope that terms like point-like, singularity and locality have the same kind of connection.

Comment: @VeronicaNoordzee Right, there is a connection between those concepts. The Lagrangian has *local* interactions like $\phi(x)^4$, where all the factors of $\phi$ are evaluated at the same spacetime point $x$. Locality is needed for *Lorentz invariance* (special relativity). However as J. Murray pointed out in his answer, products of operator-valued distributions at a single point are not well-defined, and this leads to "ultraviolet divergences." The smoothing functions are a way for us to resolve what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, my understanding is that you're asking about so-called *operator-valued distributions*, of the form
$$\Phi^\dagger(f):= \int dx \ f(x) \hat \phi_x^\dagger$$

In the canonical approach to QFT, one can loosely understand the quantum field operators $\hat \phi^\dagger_x$ and  $\hat \phi_x$ as respectively creating and destroying a particle at the point $x$.  In other words, if we take $|0\rangle$ to be the vacuum state which has no particles, then we might think of $\phi^\dagger_x |0\rangle$ as the state which contains a single particle at the point $x$ and $\phi^\dagger_x \phi^\dagger_y|0\rangle$ as the state which contains two particles - one at $x$ and one at $y$.

This is ultimately problematic, however. Just as in non-relativistic QFT, it is not possible to have a particle which is exactly localized to a point - it must be "smeared out" over some non-pointlike region of space.  As a result, $\phi_x^\dagger |0\rangle$ is not actually a physically realizable state, and $\phi_x^\dagger$ is not a well-behaved operator.

An example of a true operator is
$$\int \mathrm dx \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2} \hat \phi^\dagger_x$$
which acts on $|0\rangle$ to produce a single-particle state with wavefunction $\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. This is a perfectly well-defined state, which we obtained by integrating the "quantum field operator" $\phi^\dagger_x$ against a smooth, square-integrable function. This is what is generally meant by "smearing" a quantum field operator.

With this in mind, we define an operator-valued distribution $\Phi^\dagger$ to be an object which eats some well-behaved function $f$ and spits out a well-behaved operator

$$\Phi^\dagger(f):=\int \mathrm dx \ f(x) \hat\phi_x^\dagger$$

These are the well-defined objects which are necessary in a more mathematically rigorous formulation of QFT - though it should be said, they are rarely referenced in a first course (in my experience).

Comment: Yes, indeed, I meant operator-valued distribution. I think you did a wonderful job in linking all these concepts in such a small amount of words and equations. Could I say that in your example you 'corrected' the quantum field operator with some kind of Gaussian function and by doing so you give the created particle some area or volume to live (and not some infinitesimally small point)? By the way, I'm reading "QFT for the gifted amateur". Well, you got to be pretty gifted, in my opinion ;-)